# How to filter out long term events that fall between two dates in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to filter out events that may fall between a certain time period. These events are more than one day, so they have start dates and end dates.

I think the closest example to what I'm looking for is from this link: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4647-excel-extract-records-between-two-dates.html. The only difference is that the data in Sheet 1 also have a start and end date that are greater than a day in difference, rather than existing for a singular day.

```
=IF(ROWS(A$5:A5)>$C$2,"",INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$22,SMALL(IF((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$22>=$A$2)*(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$22<=$B$2),ROW(Sheet1!A$2:A$22)-ROW(Sheet1!$A$2)+1),ROWS(A$5:A5))))
```

The issue is that currently the start dates may not coincide with the bounds of the study dates, but that the end dates of the data in Sheet 1 do fall within these bounds.

An example of what I'm hoping to do is this:

Example:
[image]

However, instead of having the date just be a single day, I'm hoping for a way to sort through data that have a start **and** end date.

Comment: Could you provide a before/after picture example of your worksheet and what you'd like to happen?

Comment: @dwirony I've edited the post to include a picture!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution seems to work:
Assuming in Sheet1, columnA and columnB contain Start and End dates respectively.

Change the formula in C1 of Sheet2 to this, and follow the other instructions as given in your example.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$22>=A2)*(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$22<=B2)*(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$22>=A2)*(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$22<=B2))
```

Note: If this is not the output you expect then please share your expected input and output instead of from the sample.

**Edit:**
Based on your sample image I have updated the formulas. Hope this helps.

Formula for cell H2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($B$2:$B$16>=F2)*($B$2:$B$16<=G2)*($C$2:$C$16>=F2)*($C$2:$C$16<=G2))+((B2:B16<F2)*(C2:C16>=F2)*(C2:C16<=G2))+((B2:B16>=F2)*(B2:B16<=G2)*(C2:C16>G2))+((B2:B16<F2)*(C2:C16)>G2))
```

Formula for cell F5:

```
=IF(ROWS(F$5:F5)>$H$2,"",INDEX(B$2:B$16,SMALL(IF((($B$2:$B$16>=$F$2)*($B$2:$B$16<=$G$2)*($C$2:$C$16>=$F$2)*($C$2:$C$16<=$G$2))+(($B$2:$B$16<$F$2)*($C$2:$C$16>=$F$2)*($C$2:$C$16<=$G$2))+(($B$2:$B$16>=$F$2)*($B$2:$B$16<=$G$2)*($C$2:$C$16>$G$2))+(($B$2:$B$16<$F$2)*($C$2:$C$16)>$G$2),ROW(B$2:B$16)-ROW($B$2)+1),ROWS(F$5:F5))))
```

> Don't forget to press **Shift + Ctrl + Enter** when using formula in F5.
>   And then extend to other cells.

Output:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I pulled it wrong, but the formula just gave me a result of 0... I've updated the image in my original post to more accurately show what I'm hoping to do. I appreciate the try!

Comment: @ThinhTran, I have updated my answer based on your sample image.

Comment: I appreciate it, Kamal! However, I'm not sure that the formula for H2 is correct because if the start and end times are outside the bounds of F2/G2, then the row of data won't be counted, right? The formula should count data even though the start and end dates are outside of the bounds because they still overlap with F2/G2. Is that logic possible here?

Comment: @ThinhTran, sorry I was not able to give time to this question. I have updated the answer again, please try.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like that works :) I appreciate your time and effort!